# Salesforce CPQ - Product Rules Firing Timing

Tags: salesforce

We use Salesforce CPQ and I have a straightforward set up with a validation Product Rule throwing an error message when the user selects a particular combination of configuration attributes in the Configurator when they add a certain product to a quote.

Salesforce is correctly noticing that the configuration attributes trigger the product rule, and the error message is displayed - but only when the user tries to Save. The error message should be displayed as soon as the user makes the choice that triggers the rule, not when they try to save.

Why is this happening? Is there some field I'm missing to get the rule to fire at the time of the selection?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your question! To achieve the behavior you want in [Salesforce CPQ], you should adjust the rule evaluation timing of your product rule to 'Real-Time' or 'On Demand.' This way, the error message will be displayed as soon as the user makes a choice that triggers the rule, rather than only upon trying to save the quote. Additionally, consider using validation rules or custom JavaScript for more control if needed. Don't forget to involve your [Salesforce CPQ] admin or developer for proper implementation."
This response provides a summary of the steps to address the issue and encourages involving the right personnel for implementing the solution.